# NGINX listen'ing on sub1.domain.tld:port traps ALL requested sub-domains on this :port?

Tags: nginx

- nginx version: nginx/1.9.3 (Ubuntu)

I'm trying to figure out why NGINX seems to ignore limiting to a hard-coded subdomain when :port is in play, as in the following. 
*Note that :4444 is only listened to in this block.*

```
server {
    listen sub1.somedomain.net:4444 ssl;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/somedomain.net-lcrypt-config;

    root /var/www/somedomain;
    server_name sub1.somedomain.net;
}
```

The symptom is that any subdomain can be requested on :4444 and /var/www/somedomain will be served.

```
https://blech.somedomain.net
```

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms#how-nginx-decides-which-server-block-will-handle-a-request

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with domain names, but rather at what defines a network socket: a `<IP address>:<port>` duple.

In your case, it is implied all involved subdomains point to the same duple as the main one.

You configured nginx to listen on this socket, thus handling any incoming connection there. nginx then selects the best virtual server for the request, defaulting to a default one if no best match is found. I suggest you read on [how nginx serves requests](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

In your case:

1. `blech.somedomain.net` seems to be pointing to the same IP address as `sub1.somedomain.net`
2. No virtual server more suitable than the `sub1.somedomain.net` one being found for your request to `blech.somedomain.net`, it is selected to serve the request, the same as if it was having the `default_server` flag on its [`listen`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) directive.

If this is not wanted, you could (options not limites to the list below):

- use separate IP addresses for subdomains you want to isolate from each other
- create virtual servers for subdomains you want to catch
- use another virtual server as `default_server`